# How do I use a StreamReader to input text from one WPF window to another in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-structures, parameter-passing, streamreader

My problem is this, I am writing some software in WPF C# and I need to makeit so that the MainWindow will parse the txt file I have made
and store the information in a data
structure, the  data should be passed to the
second Window when it is opened. 
I have the StreamReader code working fine, it can locate the txt file, but it won't show the information in the listbox on the second window (I apologize if I have screwed up the formatting, very new to the website)

```
namespace ACW2
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void inventoryButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InventoryWindow wnd = new InventoryWindow();
        wnd.ShowDialog();



        string line;                                                                     
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"G:\P1\txt_files\inventory.txt");
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) ;
        {
            ListBox.Items.Add.(Line);
            list.Add(int.Parse(line));
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you post code don't do it in an image; use the code tags.
Seems like you don't want to use the MVVM pattern. I would recommend getting familiar with this. Nevertheless: you can create a new instance of the window you want to show and set the data as `DataContext`.

Comment: You have a rogue semicolon next to your while statement

Answer (score 1):

you have few problems here:

- semicolon on `while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) ;` line which means that next code block (in curly braces) will not be executed in the loop, but after the loop ends.
- What is `Line` (with capital L) which you are adding to `ListBox.Items` collection? Where is that `Line` defined and what is it's value?
- what is `line` (lowercase L this time)?

try to fix those errors and we'll see what's next to be done...

Comment: Okay so here is what i've got; I've fixed the semicolon, the capital L was a mistake, it should have been lowercase. In the initial code i used the string line to define the text in the streamreader. So the way I have done it is the   ListBox.Items.Add.(line);      will add the txt (the string line) to the listbox on the second window.

Comment: @BhristopherCenn after you fixed those errors, you're still not getting lines in your `ListBox`?

Comment: No, I think the issue might be that the Listbox does not exist on the mainwindow and the code is trying to put the text in there, when in actual fact the Listbox I want to send it to is on the second window. But I don't know how to send it to the inventory window when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to reach with

```
ListBox.Items.Add.(Line);
```

Maybe you mean this:

```
ListBox.Items.Add.(line);
```

You also dont need the semicolon at the end of your while statement.

**Edit:**
Specify your ListBox on the second window with a **x:Name = "myListBox"** tag.
After you did that you should be able to add an element to the listbox with **wnd.myListBox.Items.Add(line);**

Comment: I have made a list box in the main window (though this is not where I want the text to go, this is just to get it working). I get two error messages, one under add "ListBox.Items.Add.(line); is a method which is not valid given the context"  and the second is in between the first bracket and the full stop "identifier expected".  I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Well with the information of the first post we can hardly do more.
Add also the code of the second window / XAML.